# Symmetric bilinear form positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

$V$ denotes real vector space $V$ consisting of all polynomials with real coefficients/any degree so $V$ is infinite dimensional. A symmetric bilinear form is defined on V by

$$(f,g) = \int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)e^{-x} dx$$

i) State briefly why this is positive definite on $V$ (may quote any general property of real integrals).

Comment: What part of the definition of "positive definite" is causing trouble?

Comment: Hint: a definite integral of a nonnegative function is non-negative.

Answer (score 4):

A bilinear form $b$ is [positive definite](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bilinear+form) if $b(v,v) > 0$ if $v \neq 0$.

So you want to show that $(p,p) = \int_0^\infty p^2(x) e^{-x} dx > 0$ for $p(x) \neq 0$.